# Enable an end-point?

Tags: c#, json, web-services, endpoint

I'm a noob with Web Services.
Somebody sent me and email with this message:

Please, Enable an end-point that can receive JSon post messages

Im not sure about what is exactly an EndPoint.

what does it mean exactly?
I need to develop a webservice? is this a bad request?
Im learning about webservices, but "endpoint" is new for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, endpoint means the last point of a sequence of points, like a line, representing a road. In the context of web services, endpoint means a URL where the client can send a certain type of request. Note that it compiles to general terminology as in this case, the endpoint is the destination of a request.

Your task asks you to create a URL where requests can be sent from the client-side. Your specific endpoint has to support POST messages and JSON parameters.

Answer (score 0):

An Endpoint is the entity on one end of a transport layer connection.

So yes you are right. The email means you should develop a webservice that can receive a json message. But in general there is missing a lot of information about what the json will contain and what you should do with it....

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is the URL where your service can be accessed by a client application. The same web service can have multiple endpoints, for example in order to make it available using different protocols (http, https etc).

For details on how you can send and receive JSON objects check this link.
[Send Receive JSON Objects in Webservices](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Send-and-Receive-JSON-objects-to-Web-Service-Methods-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An endpoint is what a service exposes, and in WCF terms, is made up of three things:

1. Address
2. Binding
3. Contract

**Address** is the URL by which the endpoint can be reached.

**Binding** dictates transformations that are applied as well as the shape (to some degree) of the messages sent to the implementation of the Contract at the Address.

**Contract** dictates what operations are being exposed at the address. It's exactly what it says it is, it's a contract to indicate what calls are permissible.

**You can also follow this link**: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733107(v=vs.110).aspx